# Rick & morty API REACT

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, request-promise

I am using rick & morty API, and i want to render cards of the result where I display name, gender, location & episode name. But the object returns this.

```
>  "results": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Antenna Rick",
            "status": "unknown",
            "species": "Human",
            "type": "Human with antennae",
            "gender": "Male",
            "origin": {
                "name": "unknown",
                "url": ""
            },
            "location": {
                "name": "unknown",
                "url": ""
            },
            "image": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/19.jpeg",
            "episode": [
                "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10"
            ],
            "url": "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/19",
            "created": "2017-11-04T22:28:13.756Z"
        }
    ]
```

Given the episode array, I need to show the name of the episode, not the URL. So what I do in my return is this

```
<h5>{'Episode: '+getEpisode(item.episode)}</h5>

 const getEpisode = (item) => {
**//REQUEST TO https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10**
    Requests.getEpisode(item[0]).then((res)=>{
        return res.name
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

But all I got it's undefined printed in the h5 tag, why is this ? can anybody help me

this is the content of request.getEpisode

```
  const getEpisode = async (URL) => { 
//URL = https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/19
const {data: res} = await axios.get(`${URL}`);
return res;
```

};

Comment: what is Requests? ive never seen that. your question is tagged with axios so i will try to answer with that

Comment: Can you post the content of `Requests.getEpisode`? I made the assumption in my answer that this is your own method that is probably calling `axios` under the hood, but it would make your question clearer if you provide the code for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell what your `Requests.getEpisode` function does, but if you are using `axios` like your tags suggest, you could do something like this:

```js
const getEpisode = (item) => {
    axios.get(item[0]).then((res)=>{
        return res.data.name
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Depending on what your `Requests.getEpisode()` function looks like, you might just need to update the `getEpisode` function that you have in your post to return `res.data.name` instead of `res.name`

## Update:

Based on the new code OP has shared, I don't think there are any issues with how the request is made. I think the issue is that `getEpisode(item.episode)` doesn't return anything. To solve this, you could try updating a state variable after your episode is retrieved from the api. Something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const getEpisode = (item) => {
  return _getEpisode(item[0])
    .then((res) => {
      return res.name;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

const _getEpisode = async (URL) => {
  const { data: res } = await axios.get(`${URL}`);
  return res;
};

export default function App() {
  const [episode, setEpisode] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getEpisode(["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10"]).then((res) => {
      setEpisode(res);
    });
  });

  return <h5>{"Episode: " + episode}</h5>;
}
```

The api data is retrieved in the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook, and then state is updated so that the episode title displays in your component. You can see it working in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/currying-dawn-836bj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @Phil it looks like the consuming code is `<h5>{'Episode: '+getEpisode(item.episode)}</h5>`, so I think the function would have to return the string name, right (rather than the object)? Or maybe I am missed something?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were rewriting `Request.getEpisode` as opposed to just `getEpisode`

Comment: Got it. Yes, that part is confusing. I am not sure exactly what `Request.getEpisode` is...

Comment: Request.getEpisode basically it's a get from https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/10, so this returns me an object and I should print the name from the object

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. I misunderstood the original problem, but I have updated with a working solution.